# How to make images fluid width after changing their dimensions?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, responsive-design, fluid-layout

The snippet shows two groups of images in flexbox. The first is images at their original resolution that have a fluid layout. They each take up 1/3 of the width of the screen, and resize properly when you change the width of the screen so that at any time the first row has exactly 3 images.

The second group of images are cropped to a certain dimension (removing equal amounts from the top and bottom of the image and leaving the middle part). This unfortunately isn't a fluid layout. It's stuck at the hardcoded 200px amount. The first row can have 1, 2 or 3 images depending on the width of the screen.

How can I combine the two things? So the images get cropped like in the second set of images, but have a fluid layout like the first set of images and each row has exactly 3 images scaled to the right size?

```css
.container1 {
  width: 33.33%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container1 img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.container2 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container2 img {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<h1>original img</h1>
<div>
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" />
</div>
<h1>fluid layout</h1>
<div style="display:flex;flex-wrap:wrap">
  <div class="container1">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" />
    img 1
  </div>
  <div class="container1">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" />
    img 2
  </div>
  <div class="container1">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" />
    img 3
  </div>
  <div class="container1">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" />
    img 4
  </div>
</div>
<h1>resized images</h1>
<div style="display:flex;flex-wrap:wrap">
  <div class="container2">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" />
    img 1
  </div>
  <div class="container2">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" />
    img 2
  </div>
  <div class="container2">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" />
    img 3
  </div>
  <div class="container2">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" />
    img 4
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS Grid for the second case, this allows you to explicitly mention how many columns you want per row:

```
.grid-parent {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
}
```

```css
.flex-parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap
}

.flex-item {
  width: 33.33%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.flex-item img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.grid-parent {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
}

.grid-item {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.grid-item img {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<h1>original img</h1>
<div>
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" />
</div>
<h1>fluid layout</h1>
<div class="flex-parent">
  <div class="flex-item">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" /> img 1
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" /> img 2
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" /> img 3
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" /> img 4
  </div>
</div>
<h1>resized images</h1>
<div class="grid-parent">
  <div class="grid-item">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" /> img 1
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" /> img 2
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" /> img 3
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" /> img 4
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you shrink the screen width you'll see that the second group of images don't resize. It's still stuck at the hardcoded 200px width.

Comment: @user779159 just remove the hard coded widths? It seems to work.

Comment: Shrink your screen width and you'll see the heights aren't changing in the second group like they are for the first group. The images are just getting narrower and its left and right sides are getting cut off. Are you seeing something different?

Comment: Also removing those widths and heights is no longer cutting off the top and bottom of the image like I showed in my question.

Comment: @user779159 if you don't want to it get narrower you have to set at least a `min-width` or `min-height`. I don' think there is any way to do what you want if you're not going to specify either of the dimensions. Maybe when https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/aspect-ratio gets more support

Comment: For images without any further modification like in the first group they resize automatically even though there's no width or height set. Are images a special case and this behavior can't be applied to other elements?